# ColdFusion CFSpreadsheet reads empty cells

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I give my client a template that they are supposed to populate and then they upload the spreadsheet and I read the file with `cfspreadsheet` in order to copy the data into a database table.

Pretty easy. The template has only one column in it. The client can not upload a sheet with more than one column in it. This used to work.

So the one column header is `ING_CAS` but when I read the file in with `cfspreadsheet` I get `COL_2`, `COL_3`, `ING_CAS`. So not only are the blank cells getting read they are also being given default names because of this attribute `headerrow="1"`.

I'm at a loss here. I keep downloading the template and selecting the extraneous blank rows and columns and deleting them but I have no control over the file once the client gets it.

Is there some strange setting I am missing that will make `cfspreadsheet` ignore blank cells?

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFile#" query="SpreadSheetData" headerrow="1">
<cfdump var="#SpreadSheetData#" />
```

I ended up writing a helper function that stripped out COL_(n) columns.

```
<cffunction name="CleanExcelQuery" access="public" returntype="query" output="false" hint="Strips out blank column headers picked up on read.">
    <cfargument name="SpreadSheetQuery" type="query" required="true" />

    <cfset var theColumnHeaders = SpreadSheetQuery.columnList>
    <cfset var theNewColumnHeaders = "">

    <cfloop list="#theColumnHeaders#" index="h">
        <cfif uCase(left(h,  4)) IS NOT "COL_">
            <cfset theNewColumnHeaders = ListAppend( theNewColumnHeaders,  h )>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfquery name="newSpreadSheetQuery" dbtype="query">
        Select #theNewColumnHeaders#
        From SpreadSheetQuery
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn newSpreadSheetQuery />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `cfspreadsheet` code? I believe that it should ignore empty cells by default otherwise the entire blank spreadsheet would be read every time. Are you sure that the cells are blank and not filled with some "invisible" character.  Does it work as expected when you select the blank rows and columns then delete?

Comment: sounds like your xls(x) has cells that are combined and centered and it's putting ing_cas in col_3.  try rebuilding the template with ing_cas in A1 and data in A2 and upload that new spreadsheet.

Comment: have you tried just copying the values from your "dirty" spreadsheet into a new file, save it and post?  I had an issue where a client had some odd character way out of viewing range and blew up the spreadsheet.

Comment: Steve being a techie nerd I can read an error message and I copied the good column into a new spreadsheet saved and uploaded and it worked fine. End users not so much. And to be honest I gave them the blank template so they are saying my template has hidden data or something in it. There definitely isn't hidden characters I think it reads the columns as dirty if you don't select all and "Clear Contents".

Comment: Instead of having your users upload the file, why not have them paste the column into a text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cfspreadsheet` only omits cells that are *completely* blank: no value or format (such as when you select a cell and use "clear all"). If it is picking up "extra" columns, it is because one or more of the cells in that column have a value or a custom cell format. Meaning they are not really "blank".

If you know the column position, you can use the `columns` attribute to *only* read only the values in that column. For example, to read column `C`:

```
   <cfspreadsheet action="read"
            src="c:/path/to/file.xls"
            columns="3"
            headerrow="1"
            query="qResult" />
```

But I am not sure I understand why this is an issue. If you only need one column, simply ignore the other columns in your code. Can you elaborate on why this is causing an issue?

Comment: My immediate workaround was to ignore everything but the one column I required. But the issue comes back when an admin user does the same function and we allow then to have more then one column.

All of this data is being stored in a vertical table so we basically take whatever column headers they put in the spreadsheet.

And yes I agree i know that the clear all actually cleans up the spread sheet but unfortunately our users are not that tech savvy and trying to explain this process to them is not the easiest thing in the world.

Comment: If you have different levels of user access, I assume there is a login/sessions involved. You should be able to use session variables to apply different rules depending on whether or not the user has "admin" access. RE: *unfortunately our users are not that tech savvy* Yes, I was not suggesting you have the users clear the cells. I was just giving an example of what a "blank" cell means in Excel.

Comment: Yep that is how I determine if I allow you to have more than one column ... roles and permissions in the session scope. But the admin users are now getting blank columns in their uploads. See my comments above ... this data is being stored in a vertical table and whatever column headers cfspreadsheet find gets inserted into the vertical table hence COL_1, COL_2 COL_3 ....

Comment: I've posted my cleaning function above that essentially takes out the COL_(n) columns. I was more hoping for something I was missing with cfspreadsheet that would make it ignore the blank columns.

Comment: No, because they are *not* really blank. To a human yes, but not to Excel/POI, which is all that matters. Re: *vertical table* Not sure what that means. Are you saying the spreadsheet headers correspond to the names of columns in one of your database tables? If so, there may be a better option. But again, you will need to post your table DDL.

Comment: Vertical Table has three fields ID, Label, Data ... from the spread sheet ING_CAS and COL_2, COL_3 go into the Label field and the actual data for every cell goes into the Data column. Really lousy database design, there is essentially a row in teh database for every cell in the spreadsheet, but that is the way the boss wants it.

Comment: Yeah, that is a bad design, both from a performance and data integrity standpoint. If the spreadsheet headers corresponded to a table column, or even a row in a separate lookup table:  `LabelID`, `LabelText`), you could use a query to locate and validate the headers.

Comment: If at all possible, you should reconsider the design. That said, if there is no mechanism for validating the column header names, then checking for `COL_X` is probably as good as it gets. You should post your final code as an "answer".

Comment: I'm making your response the answer ... I think I left that company before making my final code the "answer"! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know which rows you want to read at all times you can use this:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#path#" query="data" headerrow="1"  excludeHeaderRow = "true"   columns = "1-5"  >
```

The above code reads columns 1 through 5. You can also use Leigh's solution to read the first 3 columns or you can do something like `columns=1,3,6` (If I remember correct) to read from a custom range

The `columns` part read only the columns you want it to read without jumping around. I used this to read files that come from our clients and usually I get a few columns that are not "blank" due to their format.

You can also check the Cf documentation for cfspreadsheet just to see what other entries the 'column' option supports.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I get the impression the number of rows and column positions can vary. If that is the case, then both the `columns` and `rows` are out, because it obviously requires knowing the range ahead of time. If the "allowed" header names were stored in a db table, then using `columns` might be a possibility. But if nothing is fixed then their current solution may be as good as it gets ...